# Pyinstaller crashes with --onedir but works with --onefile

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I am trying to build an app with Python 3.7.1 and the latest PyInstaller. GUI was programmed with PySide2. App doesn't do anything too fancy. PyInstaller builds the app fine with `--onefile` but it was quite slow to start so I wanted to create an `--onedir` app. However it gives me the error below.

```
61215 WARNING: lib not found: shiboken2.abi3.dll dependency of c:\users\XXXX\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PySide2\QtGui.pyd
61532 WARNING: lib not found: shiboken2.abi3.dll dependency of c:\users\XXXX\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PySide2\QtNetwork.pyd
61965 WARNING: lib not found: shiboken2.abi3.dll dependency of c:\users\XXXX\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PySide2\QtCore.pyd
62366 WARNING: lib not found: shiboken2.abi3.dll dependency of c:\users\XXXX\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PySide2\QtWidgets.pyd
62629 WARNING: lib not found: shiboken2.abi3.dll dependency of c:\users\XXXX\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PySide2\QtUiTools.pyd
62952 WARNING: lib not found: shiboken2.abi3.dll dependency of c:\users\XXXX\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PySide2\QtXml.pyd
72954 WARNING: lib not found: shiboken2.abi3.dll dependency of c:\users\XXXX\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PySide2\pyside2.abi3.dll
73735 INFO: Looking for eggs
73735 INFO: Using Python library c:\users\XXXX\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python37.dll
73743 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\XXXX\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\XXXX\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 111, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 63, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 844, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 791, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "app.spec", line 16, in <module>
    noarchive=True)
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 243, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 158, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 597, in assemble
    for name, path, typecode in compile_py_files(new_toc, CONF['workpath']):
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\misc.py", line 150, in compile_py_files
    with open(obj_fnm, 'rb') as fh:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\XXXX\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python37\\Scripts\\pyinstaller.exe\\__main__.pyo'
```

Same happens if I add `--debug=all`. My spec file:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(['app.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\App'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('mainwindow.ui', '.'), ('favicon.ico', '.')],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=True)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='app',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=False)
```

Command line: `pyinstaller --noconfirm --clean app.spec app.py`

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Your build command is wrong either use `spec` or pass arguments to `app.py`. `pyinstaller app.spec` or `pyinstaller --noconfirm --cleanapp.py`

Answer (score 1):

For the missing library libshiboken2.dll. (libshiboken2.dylib on MacOS and Linux)

pip install shiboken2

and then in site-packages/ shiboken2 you can find the missing libshiboken2.dll which you can copy to site-packages/Pyside2 and it works.

works the same way on MacOS and Linux as well (Libshibkoken2.dylib in those cases.)

Hope this helps someone along the way.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
pyinstaller.exe
```

Instead of just:

```
pyinstaller
```